# How to add image to ArrayList<string> in android?

Tags: android

I need to add an image into "item". item is an xml file with TextView...

```
  item = new ArrayList<String>();
   item.add("an image");
```

Comment: `ArrayList<String>` can only hold Strings.  You can store, say, the path to the image as a string, or perhaps the image itself encoded in base64.  Which are you trying to do?  If it's the latter, make it an ArrayList<File> or ArrayList<Image>.

Comment: I tried giving the path..but the output was some kind of number, maybe resource id...not an image..

Comment: This is really useful for this question: http://www.technotalkative.com/android-gridview-example/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code

```
ArrayList<Bitmap> mBit = new ArrayList<Bitmap>(9);
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
mBit.add(Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg, (i % 3) * newWidth, (i / 3) * newHeight,       newWidth, newHeight));
}
Collections.shuffle(mBit);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
Bitmap bitmap = mBit.get(i));

//Do something here 

 }
```

Comment: try adding a basic explanation, it'll help them better understand it :).

Answer (score 1):

You should create an ArrayList of objects and you can put everything you want in it and manipulate like this :

```
ArrayList<Object> array = new ArrayList<Object>();

array.put(0,"A string");
array.put(1,yourbitmap);

String string = (String) array.get(0);
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) array.get(1);
```

You must cast when you get get because it is an object array.

Answer (score 0):

If by image, you mean an image File and not Image object. Then use

```
add(fileObject.toString())
```

and while retrieving recreate File object using that object String.

new File(array.get(0)).getPath()